# How does the damage system work?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-dcote

[image]

The character has six separate areas that can be damaged:

He: head
RA: right arm
To: torso
LA: left arm
RL: right leg
LL: left leg

The degree of injury is defined on a scale 1-4 (red rectangles), requiring healing equipment from bandages to antidote  - in the picture, the left arm is more damaged than the head and three bodyparts are intact.
How does damage affect gameplay? I know that a damaged leg lowers movement speed as far as to crawling, but I'm not *yet* aware of other changes.

Comment: Menu display may be affected by [ThirteenAG's widescreen fix](https://thirteenag.github.io/wfp#callofcthulhu).